# Can Snakemake prioritize execution per-sample?

Tags: snakemake

I'm trying to create a snakemake pipeline for metagenome analysis, and some rules generate huge temporary files. This becomes a big problem when that rule is executed for all samples before the downstream rules that require those temporary files are run. I tried used priorities to force snakemake to process as many rules as possible for each sample before moving on to additional samples; however, it seems like priorities only help with choosing between multiple downstream furcating rules.

What I'm looking for is rule execution in the order of:

```
rule A --> sample1
rule B --> sample1
rule C --> sample1 
rule A --> sample2
rule B --> sample2
rule C --> sample2
```

What I keep getting is:

```
rule A --> sample1
rule A --> sample2
rule B --> sample1
rule B --> sample2
rule C --> sample1 
rule C --> sample2
```

This rule execution order produces terabytes of temporary files before the downstream rules are run and then the temporary files are deleted.
Is there a way to have snakemake prioritize to execute all rules (currently possible) for one sample before moving on to other samples?

---

The simplest solution would be to:

1. split the samples into batches
2. run the snakemake pipeline on each batch
3. delete the final aggregating rules (eg., joining all resulting tables for each sample)
4. re-run the pipeline for the final aggregation steps

While this would work, snakemake becomes less useful by itself and would have to be wrapped in a script that runs all of the batches (plus a final re-run run of the aggregation steps).

Comment: Didn't I answer this three days ago in [this](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/656/prioritize-per-sample) issue?

Comment: Sorry for the double-post. I realized that my "issue" was really just a usage question, so I posted it here and forgot to deal with the original issue. Thanks for answering my question already.

Comment: @JohannesKöster It would be good if you added your answer here, to make it more discoverable. Or, if you give permission, I can do it.

Comment: Yes, please do that.

Comment: Unable to see @JohannesKöster answer from the Bitbucket form - possibly someone can repost it here?

Comment: This is outdated now. The new Snakemake scheduling algorithm minimizes the lifetime of temporary files automatically. So, there is no need for manual prioritization here.

Comment: That's not true ... I'm dealing with the same issue with recent version.