# Snakemake - Run all rules for a given wildcard before going through to the next "batch"

Tags: python, snakemake

I have a pipeline which creates temporarily files and then deletes them later in the rule after they've been used.

```
rule all:
  input:
    expand(output_dir + "{sample}/" + "quant.sf", sample = SAMPLES)

rule name_sort:
    input:
        aligned_bam = bam_dir + "{sample}" + bam_suffix
    output:
       temp(output_dir + "{sample}_namesorted.bam")
    shell:
        """
        mkdir -p {output_dir}
        samtools sort -n -@ 2 {input.aligned_bam} -o {output}
        """

rule bam_to_fastq:
    input:
          name_sort_bam = output_dir + "{sample}_namesorted.bam"
    output:
          one = temp(fastq_dir + "{sample}_1.merged.fastq"),
          two = temp(fastq_dir + "{sample}_2.merged.fastq")
    shell:
          """
          bedtools bamtofastq -i {input} \
                        -fq {output.one} \
                        -fq2 {output.two}
          """
........

rule salmon_quant:
    input:
        fast1 = fastq_dir  + "{sample}_1.merged.fastq.gz",
        fast2 = fastq_dir  + "{sample}_2.merged.fastq.gz",
    output:
        output_dir + "{sample}/" + "quant.sf"
    params:
        out = output_dir + "{sample}",
        index_dir = salmon_index,
        threads = 4
    shell:
        """
        {my_new_salmon} quant \
        --index {params.index_dir} \
        --libType {salmon_strand_info} \
        --mates1 {input.fast1} \
        --mates2 {input.fast2} \
        --geneMap {gtf} \
        --threads {params.threads} \
        --gcBias \
        --seqBias \
        --numBootstraps 50 \
        -o {params.out} 
        """
```

This works fine, however now I'm trying to run it on a dataset of 2,000 samples. In terms of space, I have enough for the aligned BAMs, and the output of the Salmon rule, but not maintaining both the BAMS, and all the intermediate gzipped fastqs.

Is there a flag where I can tell snakemake "run the first 100 samples through all the rules that apply until you get to the end, and then submit another 100 samples"?

(I don't think the batch or jobs flags do this)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633817/can-snakemake-prioritize-execution-per-sample. See the link provided by Johannes Köster. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332350/snakemake-priorities-that-one-sample-finishes-before-next-starts. I think it would be good to have this question as a FAQ since it seems quite recurrent.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not able to open the Bitbucket link (gives me a permission error) but is the answer to use the disk_mb flag as in link 2?

Comment: I don't know what the answer on BitBucket is but it's not the same as the `disk_mb` one (at least, the two answers have different authors). BitBucket asks me for registration and I don't want to do it, so I can't tell for sure...

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, but one way is to create a sequence of 100 samples so that each subsequent calculation in the sequence is done only once the previous one is completed. Something like this (pseudocode):

```py
from toolz import partition_all
chunk_size = 100
for nchunk, chunk in partition_all(chunk_size, SAMPLES):
    rule:
        input: 
            previous_chunk = f'temp_chunk_{nchunk-1}' if nchunk>0 else None,
            samples = expand(output_dir + "{sample}/" + "quant.sf", sample = chunk),
        output: f'temp_chunk_{nchunk}'

# then include in all 'temp_chunk_19' (where 19 is 2000//100 minus 1 for zero indexing)
```

This way you will always have at most 100 samples running. The drawback is that it artificially creates bottlenecks in processing, so for example the next 100 samples will not be processed until all the previous one complete (even if there is just 1 that is missing/not computed). However, it might also be not a big deal if the calculation times are predictable and fairly similar across samples (then you can fine-tune the sample size to minimize the effect of the bottleneck).